# Refresh view after response

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, page-refresh

In one of my @RequestMapping POST methods I need to return HttpServletResponse (which is an xml file) and I want to refresh the view. Normally I would just return path but in this case it gets appended to the xml file which is being downloaded by user.
Is there any way to close and send response first and then generate(refresh) view?

Comment: Why do you need to refresh the view?

Comment: because downloading xml changes data on page and I need to have it refreshed as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say no, it's not. Not a 100 percent sure though. You could try to send the file and also set the redirect header in your response. I didn't try it just now but I guess you will just be redirected. Really depends on the browser though. A browser could decide to still download the file.

Once you sent the response a new request needs to be generated by the client, so there is no way to close it server-side and just create a new one.

I would suggest a solution using Javascript. Either AJAX or just setting the current location twice (first the download, then the new view). I'm not sure, I guess via `location.href`

Let me know if you need an actual code example, as it would take me some time to manufacture something.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I get exception appended to xml: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't sendRedirect() after data has committed to the client."

Comment: Yes, that's because headers were already sent. As I said, you can try. Maybe it works if you add the header manually.

`void addHeader(java.lang.String name, java.lang.String value)`

Comment: did you make any progress? you probably should take the javascript solution into consideration.